# In Excel - How to make the font color the same as referenced cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, fonts

I have an If Statement in Cell A1 that says IF(B1=True,A2,B2).

If it is FALSE, I want the font in Cell A1 to be RED. My Font in Cell B2 is red.

A1 correctly references A2 and B2 depending on True or False, but it keeps everything in Black Font no matter what I do with A2 or B2.

Comment: You should look into conditional formatting

Comment: Try to use Conditional Formatting: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f